# Test a model on another dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I need to evaluate the ML model on another dataset but i don't know what it fully means. I have an idea but i am not sure.
Let's say we have:

- X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test split from X,Y for the first model
- X_train_2, X_test_2, y_train_2, y_test_2  split from X2, 2 for the 2nd model

After training both model with `model.fit`, how do i test them on the other database? Is it:

```py
from sklearn.svm import SVC


#training on the first model
svm.fit(X, Y)

#test on  the 2nd model
y_pred = svm.predict(X_test_2)

#evaluate accuracy
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

It seems simple but i am really confused, i would appreciate some explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing on another dataset, say `X2, y2`, does not mean you need to split this second dataset into training & test subsets, as you have done for your original `X` & `y`. Once you have fitted your model, say `svm`, in `X` as you show, you simply predict on `X2` and compare with the labels in `y2`:

```py
# predict on the 2nd dataset X2
y_pred = svm.predict(X2)

# evaluate accuracy
print(accuracy_score(y2, y_pred))
```

Comment: Ohh I see, i had doubts about splitting the second data set too ! Thank you a lot , it's clear now

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path, but a couple of things to keep in mind:

- Once your model has been trained and you have used `model.fit`, then you can just use that model to make predictions on the second dataset using `model.predict`
- The features and the value you want to predict in the second dataset should be the same as the first dataset. Otherwise, it just doesn't make sense.
- You do not have two models. You have trained **one** model using one dataset, and then using the same model to make predictions for the second dataset.
- You do not need to divide the second dataset into X_train and X_test as the model has already been trained. What you will have, is just X_test or X2, which are all the features with all the rows for the second dataset, and y which is the value you want to predict.

Example:

- Dataset 1: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test split from X,Y for training model
- Dataset 2: X2,Y2

  ```
   from sklearn.svm import SVC

   #training on the first model
   svm.fit(X_train, y_train)

   # predict on the 2nd dataset X2
   y_pred = svm.predict(X2)

   #evaluate accuracy of predictions for second dataset
   print(accuracy_score(Y2, y_pred))
  ```

Comment: Yes, the features are the same, i am trying to see if a ("yes","no", "warning") from a parent-infant interactions (first dataset) can be recognized on an adult-robot interactions (2nd dataset) ! Thank you for your explaination !

Comment: I have a question... if we are working on 2 datasets for training and testing purposes do we need to split the training dataset let say x_train, y_train, x_test and y_test?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "the features and the value you want to predict in the second dataset should be the same as the first dataset. Otherwise, it just doesn't make sense".
If your training dataset is different (i.e., in some features) from your test dataset, model accuracy will be decreased.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Stack! Thanks for contributing. Please take the [tour](stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't already.

This is a helpful comment, but not an answer in itself. Consider posting this as a comment on the question, rather than as an answer.